# Pascal is counting backwards not upwards? so wierd

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

http://rextester.com/OXRFB95557

The watch shows the counter j going down not up...any ideas why? thanks

```
program NEACardTrick;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Math;

type
  Tcards = array[1..21] of string;    
var
   cards: Tcards = ('H A', 'H 2', 'H 3', 'H 4', 'H 5', 'H 6', 'H 7',
             'S A', 'S 2', 'S 3', 'S 4', 'S 5', 'S 6', 'S 7',
             'D A', 'D 2', 'D 3', 'D 4', 'D 5', 'D 6', 'D 7');
   shuffledCards:Tcards;
   i,j,y, x: integer;


function get_cards(var cards: array of string): Tcards;    
begin    
  y := 1;
  Repeat
    Randomize;
    x := RandomRange(1,21);
    If cards[x] <> 'Done' then
    begin
      shuffledCards[y] := cards[x];
      y := y + 1;
      cards[x] := 'Done';
    end    
  Until y >= 21;        
  result := shuffledCards;
end;

procedure PrintCards(var shuffledCards: Tcards);
var
  j: integer;
begin
  for j := 1 to 21 do
    writeln(shuffledCards[j]);
end;

begin    
  get_cards(cards);
  PrintCards(shuffledCards);
  readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your observation in Delphi 7 regarding the `j: integer` variable in `procedure PrintCards()` is exactly as it is shown in a debugger watch. However, rest assured, the `for` loop works correctly.

In your code, you have given `j` two duties, 1) to act as a loop control and 2) to act as a index to the `shuffledCards[]` array.

The compiler translates your delphi code to as efficient (but, of course, correct) machine code it can. Arranging a loop so, that detecting `ZF` (Zero Flag) as a loop terminating condition, instead of explicit comparison with a const value, is one way to improve efficiency. Therefore, duty 1) is solved by having a decrementing loop control, register `esi` in this case (see disassembly below).

For the second duty, the `esi` register can not be used, as it counts in the wrong direction. So, another register, `ebx` is used for duty 2). It is setup as a pointer to the first element of the array (the element with index 1). Then at every round in the loop `ebx` is incremented to point to the next element.

Here's a disassembly of the `PrintCards()` procedure:

```
Project2.dpr.38: begin
0040876C 53               push ebx
0040876D 56               push esi
0040876E 57               push edi
0040876F 8BF8             mov edi,eax

Project2.dpr.39: for j := 1 to 21 do
00408771 BE15000000       mov esi,$00000015    // Initialize loop control

00408776 8BDF             mov ebx,edi          // set up pointer to array
Project2.dpr.40: writeln(shuffledCards[j]);
00408778 A160934000       mov eax,[$00409360]  // loop start
0040877D 8B13             mov edx,[ebx]
0040877F E8B4B8FFFF       call @WriteOLString
00408784 E8CFA5FFFF       call @WriteLn
00408789 E8B69EFFFF       call @_IOTest

0040878E 83C304           add ebx,$04          // advance array element pointer
Project2.dpr.39: for j := 1 to 21 do
00408791 4E               dec esi              // decrement loop control
00408792 75E4             jnz -$1c             // jump if not zero to loop start

Project2.dpr.41: end;
00408794 5F               pop edi
00408795 5E               pop esi
00408796 5B               pop ebx
00408797 C3               ret
```

Put a break point on line 39 and then run. When stopped at line 39, call up the CPU view (View - Debug Windows - CPU or Ctrl-Alt-C). Then single step (F8) and follow the changes of the registers, to see for yourself

The debugger watch for `j` shows the value of `esi`, therefore you see the value going down from 21 to 1 (actually you can see the final 0 show up right after the last time `dec esi` is executed).

Answer (score 2):

Your diagnosis is incorrect. The index variable counts up in that loop.

If the loop variable is not used the The compiler might optimise the loop counter to run in which ever order it chooses. But in your loop the index variable is used and so it must be increasing.

Comment: That's my point - it is decreasing, when i press next step and inspect it it changes from a 12 to an 11 and so forth...but surely it should be going up? occasionaly happens occasionally doesn't...

Comment: I'll try to upload the actual code so you can see it running live

Comment: @TopherCharles: Add a `ShowMessage(IntToStr(j))` within the loop body. Then you'll see that `j` is increasing as it should be. However, I think it might be quite possible that your observation regarding the debugger is right. But this 'anomaly' will never affect the actual result of your program.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Just a `writeln(j)` should be enough.

Comment: @user202729: Sorry, forgot it was a command-line application. Then `writeln` is better.

Comment: Thanks - so its just a debugger fault do you reckon? wierdly my code is skipping past the writeln(j) but I'm sure you're right about this... if you make this an answer I can star it as the answer if you want...

Comment: @TopherCharles Probalby undefined behavior.

Comment: @TopherCharles You're not required to mark all questions as accepted. If they don't solve your problem you should not.

Comment: Fair point, i'll leave it open ended to see if anyone can answer it - someone has mentioned to me previously that the debugger is just faulty...

Comment: The debugger is fine. Likely the program you are debugging isn't the one with this code.

Comment: Could you be more specific please David

Comment: @TopherCharles There is [codereview.se] for reviewing working code. Also see Fisher-Yates shuffling algorithm.

Comment: Search for Fisher Yates shuffle

Comment: @TopherCharles: If the code doesn't change, there is no "occasionally it does this, occasionally it does the opposite".

Comment: There's no need to call Randomize within the 'repeat/until' loop. It's enough to call it once in the main program.